# Activate network card of Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have disabled the network card of my virtual machine in Google Cloud (right clic - Disable). Now it is impossible for me to reconnect or reactivate it. I'm new to this and can't figure out how to reactivate it.

If anyone has the solution, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reactivate the interface because the vm just lost control with Google cloud when you deactivated the network interfacte.

You need to connect to the machine using the machine serial port (like in the old days).

Open the VM from the web interface and click in "edit".
Then select "Enable connecting to serial ports " (it is the first thing you can choose), and save the changes.

Open again the VM and wou'll see in "Remote Access" you can SSH to the machine *AND* connect to the serial port.

Once you have serial port access, you can log in.
If you don't have a user in the VM (because you used your GCP user) you'll need to reboot the VM *while* you're connected to the VM using the serial console and do a root password recovery.